# vb.net Report Viewer not accessable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rdlc, reportviewer

I have installed Microsft RDLC Report Designer from Extensions. After that I created a New Item in my project and choose Report. It created Report1.rdlc. Now I want to add a ReportViewer on my form but the option is not accessable in the Toolbar.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms/). Install the NuGet Package using the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. Assuming you have a WinForms app. You didn't tag the question.

Comment: @Jimi I installed the NuGet Package and got the ReportViewer in the toolbox. However I can't add it to the form because of a Register error. ..... Microsoft/Software/Fusion!EnableLog

Comment: @Jimi you mean choose items by right clicking in the toolbar? I cant find the microsoft.reportviewer.winforms in the .NET Framework Components

Comment: Did you install this: [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms/)? If so, open up NuGet Package Manager, go to the Updates Tab; you should see one update. Perform the update. In the starting Form of your app, add in its Constructor, before `InitializeComponent()`: `SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)`. Rebuild the Solution. Close Visual Studio and open it up again. You should find the ReportView Control under the `Microsoft SqlServer` group.

Comment: Note that you need .Net Framework 4.6+ to use this package. 4.7.2+ is better.